# how opus adapts to variable bandwidth?

Tags: codec, bandwidth, opus

How does opus reacts dynamically if bandwidth in network is decreased or increased?

I am researching on it but could not find the right answer. I came to know that it supports variable bit-rate, but how does it handles changing bit-rate according to bandwidth dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

It's the application that's responsible for telling Opus what bit-rate to use. There's no bandwidth detection code in the library. Opus just makes it easier than other codecs to do bandwidth adaptation because it supports a continuous range of bitrates.